# How to set android TAB height from ActionBar?

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-actionbar

How to set android TAB height from ActionBar?

I search a lot for it. I already tried a lot of suggestions here in stackoverflow and other sites. But nothing change the TAB height, only the ActionBar height.

See this screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4ajlg8gz6kbat3/device-2013-10-31-210842.png

Im using a galaxy s4 mini android 4.2.2 to test.
Im using actionbar from compact mode.

Tab XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="42dp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```